# How to install libc6 from unstable repository on Debian?

Tags: debian, glibc

This is my server:

Linux nn15.project.org 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.46-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Debian GNU/Linux 7.1 (wheezy) Release: 7.1

I have sudo permissions. How can I install libc6 from unstable? The motivation behind is that right now I have missing GLIBC_2.14 and GLIBC_2.15.

Comment: It's not recommended that you do this, but did you try simply installing it? Version 2.19-13 currently in unstable does not appear to have any dependencies that wheezy can't meet.

Comment: This will almost certainly break things. "I have missing GLIBC_2.14 and GLIBC_2.15". Please elaborate on what this means.